# React-Redux: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

#### The objective

I have a functional component that is meant to ONLY display a list of names (players) from an array stored in the Redux state. It starts empty, but when the user presses the button of **another** component, that array gets values pushed into it.

The reason the button is stored in a separate component is that after MVP that button will be moved into a different parent component.

The component listing players is in a folder and file called PlayersCardT1, and exports a function named Players.

```js
import RowPlayer from '../RowPlayer';

const Players = (props) => {

    return (
        <ul>
        {
            props.players.map(player => (
                <RowPlayer name = { player } key = { player.id } />
            ))
        }
    </ul>
    )
}

export default Players;
```

`RowPlayer` is a simple component that just outputs a `<p>{ name }</p>`.

The index.js contains:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Players from './PlayersCardT1';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
    players: state.players
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Players);
```

#### The Error

I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

#### Attempted solution

I've tried putting the map inside a conditional, but then React complains that the component doesn't return anything, and to add return null, so I did that:

```js
if (props.players) { //Edit to remove typo from demo'd solution attempt
    return (
        <ul>
        {
            props.players.map(player => (
                <RowPlayer name = { player } key = { player.id } />
            ))
        }
    </ul>
    )
}
return null;
```

This stops errors from occurring, but the list never populates, even when the I press the button that adds the names to the array. I can see in my Redux dev tools that the state players array gets names in it, but there's no change.

Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: You should check redux devtools and see when `state.players` is set to undefined or maybe set the initial value to an empty array. It could also be that the players are not set in `state.players` but you have to check the redux devtools for that.

Comment: Since the `.map` property you are reffering to is not found it probably means that the `state.players` is not initially an array, even an empty array would dispatch the map property. It would be best if you could check the `state.players` value at the point when the `map` is used so you can add a `console.log` just before the `props.players.map` is dispatched and check if it's an array.

Comment: Looks like it should be plural players in “ if (props.player)”

Comment: Interesting, my redux devtools shows players as an empty array, however, when I console.log(props.players) as suggested by @KacperBiedka, i do indeed get "undefined" in the console. Why would that be?

my apologies, that props.player instead of props.players is a typo from when I rewrote that conditional to illustrate what I had done. It wasn't there when I actually tried it out as a solution.

Comment: Seems like your component is not recieving the redux state properly, I would search for the issue with the react component and redux state connection ;)

Answer (score 1):

there is a better way, you can check the condition with new ES6 features.

```js
    return (
        <ul>
        {
            props?.players?.map(player => (
                <RowPlayer name = { player } key = { player.id } />
            ))
        }
    </ul>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
if (props.player) {
```

here you are checking `player` instead of `players`. So change it to:

```
if (props.players) {
```

and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was done correctly, but the file was incorrectly imported into its parent component, as a result of my auto-import being unable to keep up with me moving files around

Answer (score 0):

i don't know redux but in case of react it gives an error of undefined if initialises the array like
**Not Correct**

```js
thi.state={
players:"",
}
```

**Correct**

```js
this.state={
players:[]
}
```

works fine i am limitted with the given resources